# Multiples of one component in a schematic

Tags: schematics

In this schematic, there is a quantity of 2 MOSFETs specified. Does this simply mean that two are used with the same connections? I.e. both drains connected to VIN of the LM5088, both sources connected to SW of the LM5088 and both gates connected to HG of the LM5088?

[image: SMPS]

Comment: That design looks like it comes from the TI web designer. Without telling us what part that recommends, your question is pretty meaningless. Read the "Bill of Material" that was generated alongside this schematic. But other than that, yes, that's probably the case. But if it is: that's not a usual thing to do in a schematic.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - Design is located at: [Design](https://webench.ti.com/appinfo/webench/scripts/SDP.cgi?ID=FEA960F7285095DC).

The BOM lists 2 x CSD19502Q5B ([Datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/csd19502q5b.pdf))

Comment: ah, I was hoping for a dual-mosfet package :)

Comment: It probably means use two in parallel, particularly because it's a web app, and because that FET appears to have an $\mathrm{R_{DS}_{ON}}\$ with a negative temperature coefficent, meaning that you're at least somewhat safe paralleling them.  I'm not making this my answer, though, because I still feel there's not enough info -- seeing what you *asked* for (i.e., what current out, voltage out, and voltage in are you designing for) would go a long way to reverse-engineer TI's thinking.

Comment: https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-combining-multiple-model-instances-into-one-symbol.html